# Udev rule to match usb manufacturer and kernel sd[a-z]1

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, udev

I am looking for an usb udev rule for my Raspberry Pi to match a specific manufacturer and specific kernel (sd[a-z]1) to create a symlink and run a shell script.

I've been trying now for over 2 days to get a working solution. I also tried GOTO, which unfortunately didn't work either. I created a new rule-file: /etc/udev/rules.d/1-usb.rules

Here is my code:

```
ACTION=="add", ATTR{manufacturer}!="ELPRO", GOTO="end"
ACTION=="add", ATTR{manufacturer}=="ELPRO"
KERNEL=="sd[a-z]1", SYMLINK+="elpro", RUN+="/bin/sh /home/pi/copyFromElpro.sh"
LABEL="end"
```

In this example the script runs, even if the manufacturer isn't "ELPRO".

I also tried all rules line by line individually. In this case they work as they should.

Thanks for your advice :)